# Align text inside a selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

I have a selector created as a component:

```
<my-selector
    ...
</my-selector>
```

and this is its css file:

```
my-selector{
    select {
        -webkit-appearance: none !important;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        padding: .5em;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 3px 26px;
    }
    .select-container {
        position:relative; 
        display: inline;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .select-container:after {
        content:"";  
        position:absolute; 
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .select-container:after {
        border-left: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right: 5px solid transparent;
        top: .5em;
        right: .75em;
        border-top: 5px solid black;
    }
    select::-ms-expand {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

[image]

The problem I've is the distance between the words and the left margin. I've tried margin-left, padding and others in order to remove it or make it smaller but without success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have 26px left and right padding. Have you tried adjusting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the padding via the css for the selector:

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    padding: .5em;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 3px 26px; /* this is the problem, and it's overwriting the padding attribute 4 lines up */
}
```

you need to remove the first incidence of padding, then set padding to something like:

```
padding: 3px 26px 3px 5px; /* top right bottom left */
```